# How to stop floats and classes from pushing each other down?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am simply trying to add a form to my website, however when I added it and used the  above in order for it to fit the frame, it just pushed all the content down [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8YRY.jpg)

[image]

How can I have it so it is all aligned at the top? I cannot figure out why it is being pushed down to the bottom half of the fold.

relevant code:

link to jsfiddle with css: jsfiddle.net/sz2f64hd/

```
<div class="paging">

    {$page}

</div><!-- end paging -->

</div><!-- end body -->

<div class="site">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="serve-apply">
            <div class="body">
                <ul>
                    <volist name="index_mid4" id="item">
                        <li>
                            <h4><a href="{$item.url}">{$item.title}</a></h4>
                            {$item.content}
                            <i class="{$item.title_sub}"></i>
                        </li>
                    </volist>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- end body -->

            <div class="categories">

                <div class="head">

                    <h3>categories</h3>

                </div><!-- end head -->

                <div class="body">

                    <ul>

                        <volist name="category_list" id="item">

                            <li><a href="{$item.href}"><em>{$item['title']}</em>

                                    <i class="num"></i></a></li>

                        </volist>

                    </ul>

                </div><!-- end body -->

            </div><!-- end categories -->

            <div style="clear:both;" />

            <div class="side shake-an">
                <form action="{:U('Contact/quickAdd')}" class="frm_contact">
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="1" />
                    <h3>              Request <em>FREE</em> Trial</h3>
                    <div class="form-element">
                        <input type="text" class="form-text blue" name="customer_name" id="username" placeholder="Full Name" />
                        <label for="username" class="iconfont icon-user"></label>
                    </div><!-- end form-element -->
                    <div class="form-element">
                        <input type="text" class="form-text blue" name="email" id="username" placeholder="Email" />
                        <label for="username" class="iconfont icon-letter"></label>
                    </div><!-- end form-element -->
                    <div class="form-element">
                        <input type="text" class="form-text blue" name="city" id="username" placeholder="Preferred City" />
                        <label for="username" class="iconfont icon-map"></label>
                    </div><!-- end form-element -->
                    <div class="form-element last">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div><!-- end form-element -->
                </form>
            </div><!-- end side -->
        </div><!-- end serve-apply -->
    </div><!-- end section -->
```

Comment: * { vertical-align: top; } ?

Answer (score 0):

Why does your body end before your header ?
Can you show us the CSS?
Have you tried f12 and ctrl u to analyze the code ?
Maybe there's something hidden and search the element with f12 then you can check and try the CSS

I found it:

Here :

```
 .serve-apply > .body {
```

You make

```
height:450px;
```

delete that

[image]

You have some div there thats just closed and never opened

Comment: I am not seeing where the body ends before the header, here is a jsfiddle with all the css that the webpage uses http://jsfiddle.net/m2rn59pb/ I have tried searching using f12 and ctrl u but I am not coming up with anything

Comment: Your side.shake-an div is not inside the body is that right? I mean do you want that ?